# Efficiently count data from only specific rows without VBA/Macros

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a formula to iterate over a table in Sheet1, count the total number of Yes/No/Possibly answers for each value of 'Height' e.g. collate the answers for all 'Tall' people, all 'Medium' people, and all 'Short' people separately, and return this into a table in Sheet0.

I am currently using the following formula which gives me the correct expected output that I am looking for (expected output shown in Sheet0 table), however it is very resource intesive and is causing Excel to lockup and crash.

For example, this would be the formula in what would be cell F3 (Medium/Yes/Apples) in Sheet0 below.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$B:$B="Medium")*(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet1!",$B3))=F$2))
```

My question is, does anyone know how/if this formula could be made more computationally efficient to avoid Excel crashing/freezing? I'd like to avoid writing VBA if I can help it! I should note that I need this formula to be extendable to a theoretical infinite number of rows (not that I'd have that many rows, but it can't be limited to a set number of defined rows).

Sheet0

```
+----------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Category | Cells |         Tall        |        Medium       |        Short        |
|          |       +-----+----+----------+-----+----+----------+-----+----+----------+
|          |       | Yes | No | Possibly | Yes | No | Possibly | Yes | No | Possibly |
+----------+-------+-----+----+----------+-----+----+----------+-----+----+----------+
| Apples   | C:E   | 3   | 3  | 0        | 1   | 1  | 1        | 3   | 0  | 0        |
+----------+-------+-----+----+----------+-----+----+----------+-----+----+----------+
| Bananas  | F:H   | 3   | 2  | 1        | 1   | 1  | 1        | 0   | 2  | 1        |
+----------+-------+-----+----+----------+-----+----+----------+-----+----+----------+
| Grapes   | I:K   | 4   | 2  | 0        | 2   | 1  | 0        | 2   | 1  | 0        |
+----------+-------+-----+----+----------+-----+----+----------+-----+----+----------+
```

Sheet1

```
+----------+--------+------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+------------+--------------+---------------+
|  Person  | Height | Red Apples | Green Apples | Yellow Apples | Red Bananas | Green Bananas | Yellow Bananas | Red Grapes | Green Grapes | Yellow Grapes |
+----------+--------+------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+------------+--------------+---------------+
| Person 1 | Tall   | Yes        | Yes          | No            | Yes         | No            | Possibly       | No         | No           | Yes           |
| Person 2 | Medium | No         | Yes          | Possibly      | No          | Possibly      | Yes            | No         | Yes          | Yes           |
| Person 3 | Tall   | No         | No           | Yes           | No          | Yes           | Yes            | Yes        | Yes          | Yes           |
| Person 4 | Short  | Yes        | Yes          | Yes           | No          | No            | Possibly       | Yes        | Yes          | No            |
+----------+--------+------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Full-column references and INDIRECT are both detrimental to performance here.

Answer (score 1):

The data is pivoted. Use Power Query to unpivot, load to a new table, and then you can use simpler `SUMIFS`. To use Power Query, just click on the Data tab, From Table / Range. When the Power Query editor loads, just select all the fruit columns, right-click, Unpivot. Then close and load.

[image]

In the image below, the blue table is the original pivoted data. The green table is the new unpivoted data loaded from Power Query.

The `COUNTIFS` formula in `H9` is `=COUNTIFS(Data[Height],H$7,Data[Attribute],"*"&$F9&"*",Data[Value],H$8)`. Copy and paste it to the rest of the range (do not drag it across).

[image]

More of the grouping could probably be done in Power Query if you need to avoid loading the second table.

Answer (score 0):

[See this image for a picture of the solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPi5y.png)

The formula in cell C11 is

```
=SUM(IF($C$2:$K$2 & $B$3:$B$6 & $C$3:$K$6 = $A11 & C$9 & C$10,1,0))
```

Please avoid using INDIRECT. It is a [volatile function](https://exceljet.net/glossary/volatile-function) and it will slow down your workbook considerably. You are also applying the volatile function to every row in the entire column, which is slow.